# Database or php code for small things regarding attribute option ids?

Tags: php, mysql

User profile. I have some attributes that have only 2 or 3 options. For example I store gender in table as tinyint (male=1, female=2). So in table I have tinyint but in frontend I need to display string. I have about 4 attributes that have just about 2 options.

So I have two options how to display string from option:

Create extra table where all attribute options will be stored. But in this case I need to create for such a tiny thing everytime extra join.

Or I can put in profile_helper.php all functions for this kind of attributes. For example

```
function getGender($optionId){
  $gender = $optionId == 1 ? "male" : "female";
  return $gender;
}
```

Speaking about performance, is it worth to make extra join for such a small thing?

Comment: The answer would be dictated by how likely the attributes are to change.  If static eg(gender) @nickb makes sense otherwise the way I suggested may work better

Comment: What's in your DB (and which DB) and in your code are two pair of shoes. Large chunks of your code should not care if and how the user is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your life easier and [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) all of the possibilities, like so:

```
`gender` ENUM( 'MALE', 'FEMALE')
```

That way, you literally insert the values `'MALE'` or `'FEMALE'` into the database, and when you retrieve the values from the database, you will get back one of those strings, and the only helper functions you may need is [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/ucfirst) or [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower).

I would only recommend this approach for things that are highly unlikely to be changing (of which gender is a perfect example).

Comment: I just read http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/. At the end the author made conclusion "As you can see, ENUM and VARCHAR results are almost the same, but join query performance is 30% lower.". So if this is the case, why would I even use ENUM for such cases, why not simple put varchar?

Comment: For many reasons. 1) That article was written in 2008, 2) ENUM limits the possibilities, where as VARCHAR will take anything, and 3) I highly doubt this would ever be identified as the bottleneck to your application. If, after profiling and query optimization, this is determined to be the bottleneck, then your application must be incredibly efficient, at which point you can transition directly to VARCHAR without losing column values. 4) ENUM is straightforward (looking a the DB, who knows which one of (0,1) corresponds to (male,female))

Answer (score 0):

I would defintely go the SQL route.  More scalable in the future. Obviously not an issue with Gender but depending on what the other options are it may save you some time down the road. So something like:

```
SELECT tblGender.gender FROM tblGender, tblUser WHERE tblUser.genderID = tblGender.genderID AND tblUser.userID = "x"
```

Comment: I think though he's talking about an attribute table that would store attributes for the user instead of a specific table for gender

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of attribute tables. The SQL doesn't optimize as well. Some things should be normalized to another table. Some things should not. It really depends on your structure and what you're trying to do.

In the case of gender if you're building a multi-lingual app that's something that needs to map to your language tools anyway so a function or constants or ENUMs in the database are really all fine for any data that isn't likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If it's gender and it definitively will not grow - a constants class is something I would do.

```
class Constants {

    public static $gender = array(0 => 'male', 1 => 'female');

    public static function getGender( $value ) {

        if ( !empty(self::$gender[$value])) {
            return self::$gender[$value];
        }
    }
}
```

Mighty useful, if you want to encapsulate and do, i.e.:

```
echo Constants::getGender($user->gender);
```

If however you want values you will change often, please go the SQL way, since it is not good to hardcode stuff unless it is a "genderlike" issue.

IMHO, no need to do joins for this, since gender will never be more than male and female.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would have a second table.  It's flexible, scalable, easy to change or add genders (ie, not specified)

```
SELECT person.id, gender.name
FROM person
INNER JOIN gender
ON person.genderid = gender.id
```

It's still very efficient performance wise.  It just seems silly because there's only two values right now, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't follow normalization rules.